# Which credit and debit cards are supported by Apple Pay

Tags: apple-pay

Which credit and debit cards are currently supported by Apple Pay? Is there an official list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this article for an up-to-date list and more information on which cards are supported: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6288.

There is also a list on [iGeeksBlog](http://www.igeeksblog.com/list-of-banks-and-credit-cards-that-support-apple-pay/).

Comment: Apple keeps a uptodate list in the linked support document, there is no value in maintaining a separate list here